# How to ignore a specific string while searching for a pattern in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I have a query where I replace all the keywords specified in the pattern with the keyword enclosed in square brackets.

if my query already has `Select [key] from table1`, I should ignore and avoid replacing it:

```
var pattern = @"(?i)Key|IN|ON|VIEW";
var subject = "Select key from table1";
var result = Regex.Replace(subject, pattern, @"[$0]");
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookaheads to ignore matching `[` and `]` surrounding your keywords:

```
var pattern = @"(?i)(?<!\[)(?:Key|IN|ON|VIEW)(?!\])";
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rR4mK4/1)

Comment: Thanks Anubhav..it worked. but could you please tell me what does (?<!\[)(?:  and (?!\]) do.I din't get how it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Link I provided has explanation of this regex on RHS. Also look at this very helpful article on lookarounds in regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html